# how to install puppeteer for AWS lambda inside docker?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, aws-lambda, puppeteer

i'm trying to generate pdf file for this service i'm building with typescript. now everything works locally but i can't deploy it to AWS as it exceeds the lambda limit. now i am trying to dockerize it and it get's deployed but throws the following error.

```
"Failed to launch the browser process!\n/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-1036745/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"
```

this is where it fails

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: args,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
```

and here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14.2022.09.09.11
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task"

# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy package.json
COPY package.json ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

# Copy handler function and tsconfig
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Compile ts files
RUN npm run build

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "dist/src/generate.pdf" ]
```

Comment: I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda to create a lambda function that is small enough to be uploaded so making a docker image would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A Working example...

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:latest

ENV PATH /opt/node_app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED 1
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

RUN yum install wget curl -y
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_*.rpm -y

COPY package.json ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY server.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN npm install
RUN npm cache clean --force

CMD [ "server.main" ]
```

Puppeteer config

```
const options = {
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
    args: [
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-gpu'
    ]
};
```

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't working out for me. i get internal server error without showing any error logs!

Answer (score -1):

i did a workaround from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-run-puppeteer-and-headless-chrome-in-a-docker-container/) so i changed my Dockerfile as below

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get install -y \
    fonts-liberation \
    gconf-service \
    libappindicator1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-1.0\
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgbm-dev \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libpng-dev \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    xdg-utils \
    chromium-browser

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14.2022.09.09.11
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task"

# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy package.json
COPY package.json ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

RUN chmod -R o+rwx node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium


# Copy handler function and tsconfig
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Compile ts files
RUN npm run build

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "dist/src/generate.pdf" ]
```

and my code as below

```
export async function generatePdf(
  file: FileType,
  options?: OptionsProps,
  callback?: CallBackType
) {
  let args = [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-gpu',
  ];

  if (options?.args) {
    args = options.args;
    delete options.args;
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: args,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
```

now i'm getting another error

```
"Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/google-chrome ENOENT\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"
```

if i remove the `executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'` then still getting error but diffferent one

```
"Failed to launch the browser process!\n/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-1036745/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

i, then found another solution [here](https://paul.kinlan.me/hosting-puppeteer-in-a-docker-container/)

so i changed my Dockerfile

```
FROM kinlan/puppets:latest

# Copy the app
COPY . /app/
#COPY local.conf /etc/fonts/local.conf
WORKDIR app
RUN npm i && npm run build

# Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser ./node_modules

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

EXPOSE 8084
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "dist/src/generate"]
```

and my code as same before

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--headless',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  ];,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
  });
```

and now i get a different error

```
START RequestId: 798fff12-3289-4a8b-90b4-72b724506f67 Version: $LATEST
/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:366
for await (const chunk of readable) {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/BrowserConnector.js:42:19)
END RequestId: 798fff12-3289-4a8b-90b4-72b724506f67
```

Answer (score -1):

now i have tried another solution from [here](https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c)

my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14

RUN yum install -y wget unzip libX11

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm && \
    yum install -y google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task"

# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy package.json
COPY package.json ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

# Copy handler function and tsconfig
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Compile ts files
RUN npm run build

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD [ "dist/src/generate.pdf" ]
```

and my code

```
export async function generatePdf(
  file: FileType,
  options?: OptionsProps,
  callback?: CallBackType
) {
  let args = [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-gpu',
  ];

  if (options?.args) {
    args = options.args;
    delete options.args;
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: args,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
  });
```

and i get this error `"Protocol error (Target.setAutoAttach): Target closed."`

```
2022-09-15T05:46:28.039Z    a251301b-87b7-4e34-bf7c-c1d0a42ae6f5    ERROR   ProtocolError: Protocol error (Target.setAutoAttach): Target closed.
    at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:104:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.send (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:100:16)
    at ChromeTargetManager.initialize (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ChromeTargetManager.js:253:82)
    at Browser._attach (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:219:73)
    at Function._create (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:201:23)
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:92:50)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async generatePdf (/var/task/dist/src/helpers/makePdf.js:21:21)
    at async Runtime.pdf [as handler] (/var/task/dist/src/generate.js:21:29) {
  originalMessage: ''
}
```

Answer (score -1):

updated my Dockerfile
i'm using a build and copying to my own build

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"
FROM node:slim as build-image
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}/
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN ls ${FUNCTION_DIR}
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN npm install

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:latest
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN ls ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY package.json ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN npm install
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

RUN npm run build
RUN ls ${FUNCTION_DIR}/node_modules
RUN node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
CMD [ "/function/dist/api/generate.pdf" ]
```

but getting this error:
`"Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/google-chrome ENOENT\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"`